# Change input border color if text is typed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think that Title of my question explains very well what i need. For example my code is

```
<head> 
<style>
input{ border: 5px solid red;}
</style>
</head>
    <div class="in">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="text" method="post">
        </div>
```

Now border is Red. I need  to make it black if i will write text in it. Thanks

Comment: Please, try always to add to your questions your best code that shows an effort from your side in resolving your own issue! Cons is that usually you'll also get comments of what you were doing wrong which in my opinion is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputName = document.querySelectorAll("[name=text]")[0];

inputName.addEventListener("input", function(){
  var hasVal = this.value.trim().length > 0
  this.style.border = "5px solid "+ (hasVal? "black" : "red");
});
```

```css
input{ border: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" name="text" method="post">
```

The above will also return back to RED if you remove any value.
If you want to keep it black regardless of the value length than:

```js
var inputName = document.querySelectorAll("[name=text]")[0];

inputName.addEventListener("input", function(){
  this.style.border = "5px solid #000";
});
```

```css
input{ border: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" name="text" method="post">
```

Comment: Just awesome. Thank you so much <3

Comment: @davidxoma :D you're welcome! <3